# Having trouble in installing Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS alongside Win 7 (64-bit)

Tags: windows-7

I am new to Ubuntu.  I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS through UnetBootin.  As I go through the steps, I see that i am never asked the option to install Ubuntu alongside my existing OS (Windows 7). Do I need to partition the hard drive before installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 7?  It's pretty confusing.  I eagerly look forward to some help in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Installing Ubuntu without partitioning was able in Ubuntu 12.04 thanks to [Wubi software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wubi_%28software%29)
Development is disconntinued and Ubuntu 14.04.2 isn't supported.

Don't be affraid, Ubuntu installers are safe, follow them and let the installer to partition your disk.

Luck!

Comment: Hi, I am getting this error right on the installation menu.  I don't have the option for choosing installation alongside Windows. Here's the message I get:  **Your installation medium in on /dev/sda2.  You will not be able to create,delete, or resize partitions on this disk, but you may be able to install to existing partitions there.**  What does this mean?  Do I have to create a partition for Ubuntu, with swap, root folders first?

Comment: OK, edit your first question, and add a photo where we can see the error and we can see existing partitions. Thank's

Comment: I can't attach an image, until I at least have a reputation of 10.  It's sucks why do I need to have that number of reputation.

Comment: OK, I was installing ubuntu in my pather PC, and says the same: /dev/sda is your installatin medium, usb ?  It's saying that you cannot modify this medium ( sda). Ofcourse you must install UBUNTU on other medium , do you have sdb sdc... ? Try this tutorial [win7+ubuntu](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/dual-boot-windows-7-ubuntu.html)

Comment: No, I only have /dev/sda, /dev/sda1 [Windows 7 (loader)], and /dev/sda2.  What do they mean actually?

Comment: Start live USB UBUNTU, resize your disk ( perhaps sda2) for realese free space to create new partitions. This tutorial is more updated [Win7+ubuntu14](http://incisiveradar.com/how-to-install-ubuntu-14-04-alongside-windows-7/)

Comment: Thanks for your help so far.  I am wondering if I create a bootable USB Ubuntu, instead of using the UnetBootin application. Is there a difference between creating a virtual bootable USB drive and an actual physical USB drive?

Comment: In Ubunt is better use another program, take a look to [How to create a bootable USB stick on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)

Comment: Hi.  I was able to install Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS using a bootable USB stick.  It went absolutely seamless.  Thanks for your patience and support.  Now time to get hands on Ubuntu!